# Restore admin share C$

Tags: windows, network-shares

My admin share C$ has been removed causing our server-managed security  (Sophos Endpoint Security and Control) to stop updating this workstation because it is unable to create local tasks.

I've searched for two days now; lots of stuff about disabling C$ or allowing network access via a Registry edit but nothing about restoring a missing "default admin share C$".

I can recreate C$ from the MMC but it's removed after a reboot.

System is Windows 7 Pro 64-bit on a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155345) article?  It's for Windows NT 4, but the symptoms and fix steps seem like they might still work on a modern Windows.

The symptom it lists is

> When you use Server Manager or the "NET USE /D" command to stop sharing a shared, administrative folder (such as ADMIN$ or C$), users are unable to access files or folders on the shared location.

So it seems like the `C$` share should be covered by the advice.  One of the suggested fixes is

> Type the following commands from a command prompt: net share sharename$

So in your case, I'm guessing you would type

> net share c$

Apologies for not trying myself - I don't have a test machine handy at the moment.

Comment: Hi dsolimano, from a reboot C$ is missing from the share list under Computer Management (local), Shares & running "net share C$" in a administrator command window yields "This shared recourse does not exist."

Comment: Using the Create A Shared Folder Wizard to recreate C$ with "Administrators have full access; other have read-only access" & running net share C$ again the command completes successfully.
Obviously I have to reboot & test to see if Sophos can now push down the updates... will get back with the results. Thanks
Nick

Comment: No luck the C$ share is gone after a reboot - the culprit appears to be Tuneup Utilitis which I tried once before uninstalling.
It appears to have removed C$ share as a security risk. Now the question is how to restore the C$ share?

Answer (score 0):

Usually rebooting should fix the problem, if someone remove it.

if its not recreated, Check [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842715) to see if the windows share autocreate settings where changed.

If all fails, try restarting the server service and check the event viewer for errors, it should say something